# AngularJS sending file to Google Blobstore - Blob Key retrieved as 'null'

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I want to send a video file to GAE Blobstore using AngularJS, following are the code snippet.

I am getting the upload url through endpoint API call and using it in Form action field and http POST call.

When the BlobKey was retrieved it was always returned as *null*. The admin console has entry for the item in '*BlobUploadSession*', but I could not verify whether the video file was uploaded.

How to identify whats going wrong when the BlobKey was retrieved?

HTML:

```
<form name="videoForm" action="{{uploadUrl}}" ng-init="init()" novalidate role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Video Title</label>
        <input id="title" type="text" name="title" ng-model="video.title"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>             
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="videoFile">File Path</label>
        <input id="videoFile" type="file" name="videoFile" class="form-control"
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)"/>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addVideo(videoForm)" class="btn btn-primary">Video Add
    </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
videoApp.controllers.controller('videoAddCtrl',
    function ($scope, $log, $http, oauth2Provider, HTTP_ERRORS) {

$scope.video = $scope.video || {};

$scope.init = function () {
    gapi.client.video.getUploadUrl().
        execute(function (resp) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            if (resp.error) {
                if (resp.code && resp.code == HTTP_ERRORS.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    oauth2Provider.showLoginModal();
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                console.log(resp.result.uploadUrl);
                $scope.uploadUrl = resp.result.uploadUrl;
            }
        });
    });
};

$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log($scope.files);
    console.log($scope.uploadUrl);
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: $scope.uploadUrl,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        data: {
            file: $scope.files,
        },
        transformRequest: function(data) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                formData.append(key, value);
            });
            return formData;
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log("video " + $scope.video.title + " Successfully Uploaded");
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
};

$scope.addVideo = function (videoForm) {
    console.log($scope.video.title);
    $scope.submit(videoForm);
};

$scope.setFile = function(element) {
    $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
        $scope.files = element.files;
        console.log($scope.files);  
    });
}

});
```

Java Servlet:

```
public class UploadVideo extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(UploadVideo.class.getName());

    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService =
                BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Log.info("+Enter");

        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("videoFile");

        Log.info("Blob Key: " + blobKeys);

        if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
            Log.info("Blob is null or empty");
            res.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            Log.info("Serve blob");
            res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());
        }

        Log.info("-Exit");
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form declaration.

Comment: I tried that option, it is not helping.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?